# Complex Number in Polar Form with 6th root

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

> Express $(\sqrt{3} + i)^6$ in polar form.

Normally, it would be $2(cos(\pi/6) + i sin (\pi/6))$ but how about the 6? I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)

Comment: De Moivre's theorem.

Comment: This is trigonometry form not polar!

Comment: @MyGlasses Is there a significant difference between writing $re^{i\varphi}$ or $r(\cos\varphi+i\sin\varphi)$?

Comment: @egreg The main difference between them is the using of them. in most cases polar form used in circular usage.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$(\sqrt{3}+i)^6= \left(2e^{i \frac{\pi}{6}}\right)^6$